# How to remove duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, records

good work.

Create Code:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Blok]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blok](
    [blok_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [blok_l_id] [int] NULL,
    [blok_isim] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Blok] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [blok_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DaireGecmis]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DaireGecmis](
    [dg_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dg_d_id] [int] NULL,
    [dg_p_id] [int] NULL,
    [dg_islemtarihi] [datetime] NULL,
    [dg_islem] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dg_giristarihi] [date] NULL,
    [dg_cikistarihi] [date] NULL,
    [dg_karartarihi] [date] NULL,
    [dg_feragattarihi] [date] NULL,
    [dg_tahsisturu] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dg_aciklama] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dg_kesintiyazildimi] [bit] NULL,
    [dg_kararid] [int] NULL,
    [dg_yonetimeyazildimi] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DaireGecmis] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dg_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Daireler]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Daireler](
    [d_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [d_kod] [int] NULL,
    [d_il] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_ilce] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_semt] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_mahalle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_aciklama] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [d_cadde] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_sokak] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_blok] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_apartman] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_no] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_metrekare] [int] NULL,
    [d_oda] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [d_giriskat] [bit] NULL,
    [d_ustkat] [bit] NULL,
    [d_l_id] [int] NULL,
    [d_blok_id] [int] NULL,
    [d_p_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Daireler1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [d_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Lojmanlar]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lojmanlar](
    [l_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [l_isim] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [l_turu] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Lojmanlar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [l_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Personel]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Personel](
    [p_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [p_tc] [nvarchar](11) NULL,
    [p_adsoyad] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [p_kurumsicil] [int] NULL,
    [p_gorevunvani] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [p_gorevyeri] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [p_istel] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [p_ceptel] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [p_hizmetyil] [int] NULL,
    [p_hizmetay] [int] NULL,
    [p_hizmetgun] [int] NULL,
    [p_oncekilojmanyil] [int] NULL,
    [p_oncekilojmanay] [int] NULL,
    [p_oncekilojmangun] [int] NULL,
    [p_ankaraiciev] [int] NULL,
    [p_ildisiev] [int] NULL,
    [p_disiplincezasi] [bit] NULL,
    [p_medenihal] [bit] NULL,
    [p_cocuksayisi] [int] NULL,
    [p_annebaba] [int] NULL,
    [p_esininmeslegi] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [p_esyillikgelir] [int] NULL,
    [p_hakimsavci] [bit] NULL,
    [p_puan] [int] NULL,
    [p_d_id] [int] NULL,
    [p_mazeret] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [p_sira] [int] NULL,
    [p_feragat] [bit] NULL,
    [p_giriskat] [bit] NULL,
    [p_ustkat] [bit] NULL,
    [p_vpuan] [int] NULL,
    [p_evadresi] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_personel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [p_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blok] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blok] ([blok_id], [blok_l_id], [blok_isim]) VALUES (56, 22, N'A/3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blok] ([blok_id], [blok_l_id], [blok_isim]) VALUES (61, 22, N'A/12')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blok] ([blok_id], [blok_l_id], [blok_isim]) VALUES (70, 27, N'C/1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Blok] ([blok_id], [blok_l_id], [blok_isim]) VALUES (1072, 1028, N'C/12 BLOK')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Blok] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (1003, 1384, 2699, CAST(0x0000A53800E4AFEC AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0x802F0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x4B3A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (1026, 1397, 1987, CAST(0x0000A54400E5BF2D AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0xBC350B00 AS Date), CAST(0x993A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (1432, 1298, 2217, CAST(0x0000A53800E3AF34 AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0xAD200B00 AS Date), CAST(0x9D390B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (1435, 1300, 2221, CAST(0x0000A53800E3FA15 AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0xF5330B00 AS Date), CAST(0x723A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (1486, 1550, 2470, CAST(0x0000A53800E61215 AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0x971C0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x673A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (2881, 2658, 2601, CAST(0x0000A538007B3873 AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0xDD320B00 AS Date), CAST(0x5D3A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (2886, 2687, 2160, CAST(0x0000A5380080E315 AS DateTime), N'Tahliye Edildi', CAST(0x35320B00 AS Date), CAST(0xB8390B00 AS Date), CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), NULL, NULL, N'', 1, 1, 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (4918, 2687, 5813, CAST(0x0000A54600D5BDC4 AS DateTime), N'Feragat Etti', NULL, NULL, CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), CAST(0xA13A0B00 AS Date), NULL, N'', 0, 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (4930, 1414, 5825, CAST(0x0000A546009AA675 AS DateTime), N'Feragat Etti', NULL, NULL, CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), CAST(0x933A0B00 AS Date), NULL, N'', 0, 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] ([dg_id], [dg_d_id], [dg_p_id], [dg_islemtarihi], [dg_islem], [dg_giristarihi], [dg_cikistarihi], [dg_karartarihi], [dg_feragattarihi], [dg_tahsisturu], [dg_aciklama], [dg_kesintiyazildimi], [dg_kararid], [dg_yonetimeyazildimi]) VALUES (4938, 1384, 2567, CAST(0x0000A54C014A502F AS DateTime), N'Feragat Etti', NULL, NULL, CAST(0x933A0B00 AS Date), CAST(0xA73A0B00 AS Date), NULL, N'', 0, 2, 0)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DaireGecmis] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (1298, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'ATAKENT ', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'31', 130, N'3', 0, 1, 22, 56, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (1384, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'8', 130, N'3', 0, 0, 22, 61, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (1397, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'20', 130, N'3', 0, 0, 22, 61, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (1414, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'37', 130, N'3', 0, 0, 22, 61, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (1550, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'23', 102, N'3', 0, 0, 27, 70, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (2658, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'10', 112, N'3', 0, 0, 1028, 1072, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] ([d_id], [d_kod], [d_il], [d_ilce], [d_semt], [d_mahalle], [d_aciklama], [d_cadde], [d_sokak], [d_blok], [d_apartman], [d_no], [d_metrekare], [d_oda], [d_giriskat], [d_ustkat], [d_l_id], [d_blok_id], [d_p_id]) VALUES (2687, 0, N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'39', 112, N'3', 0, 0, 1028, 1072, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Daireler] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Lojmanlar] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Lojmanlar] ([l_id], [l_isim], [l_turu]) VALUES (22, N'ELVANKENT', N'Vakıf')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Lojmanlar] ([l_id], [l_isim], [l_turu]) VALUES (27, N'KONUTKENT', N'Vakıf')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Lojmanlar] ([l_id], [l_isim], [l_turu]) VALUES (1028, N'URANKENT', N'Vakıf')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Lojmanlar] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (1987, N'13238255210', N'BAYRAM SALEN', 42128, N'ÇİFTÇİ', N'ANKARA', N'(   )    -', N'(505) 542-4317', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2160, N'36736723608', N'ATILLA TAYDAC', 35736, N'BAKKAL', N'İSTANBUL', N'(   )    -', N'(542) 575-2071', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2217, N'22236137600', N'YAKUZ KEKTEN', 32486, N'BERBER', N'ÇORUM', N'(   )    -', N'(050) 536-7325', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2470, N'45512304590', N'KACUR DOGAN', 21909, N'KASAP', N'KIRŞEHİR', N'(   )    -', N'(312) 416-1823', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2567, N'19238379708', N'FATIH KOSEKACA', 105281, N'MANAV', N'ÇANKIRI', N'(   )    -', N'(507) 062-4336', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2601, N'29926623496', N'AYE SOY', 400214, N'MARANGOZ', N'BALIKESİR', N'(   )    -', N'(530) 540-6921', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (2699, N'54239361302', N'DURUN AYR', 32324, N'DEMİRCİ', N'YENİŞEHİR', N'(   )    -', N'(505) 488-2323', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (5813, N'40759022396', N'SELAT GCRAY', 34238, N'ELEKTRİKÇİ', N'ESKİŞEHİR', N'(   )    -', N'(505) 227-2369', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Personel] ([p_id], [p_tc], [p_adsoyad], [p_kurumsicil], [p_gorevunvani], [p_gorevyeri], [p_istel], [p_ceptel], [p_hizmetyil], [p_hizmetay], [p_hizmetgun], [p_oncekilojmanyil], [p_oncekilojmanay], [p_oncekilojmangun], [p_ankaraiciev], [p_ildisiev], [p_disiplincezasi], [p_medenihal], [p_cocuksayisi], [p_annebaba], [p_esininmeslegi], [p_esyillikgelir], [p_hakimsavci], [p_puan], [p_d_id], [p_mazeret], [p_sira], [p_feragat], [p_giriskat], [p_ustkat], [p_vpuan], [p_evadresi]) VALUES (5825, N'46582331814', N'MAT AKSAKAL', 138934, N'BOYACI', N'ŞIRNAK', N'(   )    -', N'(554) 349-1226', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, N'', 8, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Personel] OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Index [MÜKERRER SİCİL GİRİŞ ENGELİ]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Personel] ADD  CONSTRAINT [MÜKERRER SİCİL GİRİŞ ENGELİ] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [p_kurumsicil] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

GO
/****** Object:  Index [MÜKERRER TC GİRİŞ ENGELİ]    Script Date: 11.11.2015 10:46:14 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Personel] ADD  CONSTRAINT [MÜKERRER TC GİRİŞ ENGELİ] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [p_tc] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Select Code:

```
SELECT
    Daireler.d_id, Daireler.d_l_id, Daireler.d_blok_id, Daireler.d_p_id, Daireler.d_no,
    Blok.blok_id, Blok.blok_isim, Lojmanlar.l_id, Lojmanlar.l_isim, Lojmanlar.l_turu,
    DaireGecmis.dg_id, DaireGecmis.dg_d_id, DaireGecmis.dg_p_id, DaireGecmis.dg_cikistarihi,
    DaireGecmis.dg_feragattarihi, DaireGecmis.dg_aciklama, Personel.p_id, Personel.p_adsoyad,
    Personel.p_kurumsicil, Personel.p_gorevunvani, Daireler.d_metrekare, Daireler.d_oda,
    Daireler.d_giriskat, Daireler.d_ustkat, Daireler.d_aciklama
FROM
    Daireler
    INNER JOIN Blok ON Daireler.d_blok_id = Blok.blok_id
    INNER JOIN Lojmanlar ON Daireler.d_l_id = Lojmanlar.l_id
    INNER JOIN DaireGecmis ON Daireler.d_id = DaireGecmis.dg_d_id
    INNER JOIN Personel ON DaireGecmis.dg_p_id = Personel.p_id
WHERE
    (Daireler.d_p_id IS NULL) AND (Lojmanlar.l_turu = 'Vakıf')
ORDER BY
    Lojmanlar.l_turu, Lojmanlar.l_isim, Blok.blok_isim,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Daireler.d_no) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Daireler.d_no) = 1 THEN CAST(Daireler.d_no AS INT) ELSE 0 END,
    Daireler.d_no
```

Result:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLYOZ.png)

my problem
multiple `DaireGecmis.dg_d_id` if there is `DaireGecmis.dg_id`, which will bring extra records.

I've marked the places I do not want to appear yellow.
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quTZv.png)

Thank you for your help.

The creator and insert the code database information I have given above.
After you add this code on your system, run the query code I provide below.
I reported on the results of the picture.
2. In the picture I have painted with yellow lines point I want this filter available.

This query will allow filtration to send you to me?

Comment: It's best if images that are part of your question are included directly in the question. Links tend to go bad over time. Also, some people who might be able to answer your question will skip your question rather than click on external links, so it reduces your chance of an answer.

Comment: [Result](http://imageshack.com/a/img907/8881/STTnzm.png)


[İmage 2](http://imageshack.com/a/img910/9545/k5XZms.png)

Comment: And what do you want to do with the columns that are different in the 2 similar lines? Like "DURUN AYR" and "FAITH KOSEKACA". If you drop one of the lines, you can only keep one of them.

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicated rows, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`. Your code look like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY duplicated columns ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
   FROM Your_Table_Result
) AS A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Example: I have a table result called `TBR` like:

```
ID C1 C2 C3
1   1  2  1
1   1  2  2
1   2  2  1
1   2  3  1
```

And I want to remove rows which duplicate `ID C1 C2` columns and get `MAX C3`

Result LIKE:

```
ID C1 C2 C3
1   1  2  2
1   2  2  1
1   2  3  1
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, C1, C2 ORDER BY C3 DESC) AS RN
   FROM TBR
) AS A
WHERE RN = 1
```

If I want to get `MIN C3`, I `ORDER BY C3`. If I want to get `top down C3`, I `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`

Comment: you can answer through my example?